# Getting unwanted curve using subdivision surface modifier

Tags: modeling

I am making my first car in blender.  I watched BlenderGuru tutorials about using the subdivision surface modifier.  I use edge creases on any hard edge like he said.  At the top back of the car I used edge creases but I am still getting an unwanted curve where its supposed to be 90 degree angle.  I understand the use of this modifier but its harder to work with.[Lamborghini file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndHU9.png)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Subdivision Surface* modifier round the shape between these 2 faces and your *Edge Crease* can't prevent it:

[image]

If you create these edges it will fix your problem, but maybe try a topology without crease, because crease can't always fix this kind of problems.

[image]

Comment: Ok thank you.  I should have known that.